# Power sequencing with LDO without enable pin

Tags: power, dac, texas-instruments, power-sequencing

What is the right way to provide a power sequence using LDO (or any other power source) without the enable pin?

I'm using [DAC7718](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac7718.pdf) from Texas Instruments and it require a quit complex power sequencing:

> For proper power-on initialization of the device, IOVDD and the digital pins must be applied before or at the same
>   time as DVDD. If possible, it is preferred that IOVDD and DVDD can be connected together in order to simplify the
>   supply sequencing requirements. Pull-up resistors should go to either supply. AVDD should be applied after the
>   digital supplies (IOVDD and DVDD) and digital initialization pins (LDAC, CLR, RST, CS, and RSTSEL). AVSS can
>   be applied at the same time as or after AVDD. The REF-x pins must be applied last.

Hence I need to:

1. apply IOVDD and DVDD togheter
2. apply AVDD and AVSS
3. apply REF-x

In my circuit IOVDD and DVDD are +3.3V and come from a MCP1703; AVDD is +12V and comes from an AC/DC converter (TUHS15F12); AVSS is -12V and come from an ICL7660; REF-x is 2.5V and come from REF3025.

The simplest way I'm thinking at is to use some mosfet controlled by the MCU:

- IOVDD and DVDD go straight to the DAC7718
- AVDD is fed by a PMOS
- AVSS is fed by a NMOS
- REX-x is fed by a PMOS

of course I will need some interfacing/level translation to control those mosfet from a 3.3V.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: This seems fine. I would just put the REF PMOS at the REF3025 input rather than its output so the Rdson does not affect the ref voltage.

Comment: There are also power sequencing ICs around in case you don't want to do it yourself - but I'm not sure if one is around which handles -12 V.

Comment: @Arsenal yes, I searched for that ICs but I found only power sequencing ICs that control enable pins or just distribute the same power input to multiple outputs.

Comment: There is [this](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC2924) which can control NMOS, but yeah I see that it could be a bit of a trouble finding the right one and if you already have a MCU which can do it, it's probably fine to use it.

Comment: I don't think that the "straight" application of IOVDD & DVDD, is correct. Its application must be under your control, so that you can apply the voltages in the proper sequence.

Comment: @Guill the datasheet says: "If possible, it is preferred that IOVDD and DVDD can be *connected together* in order to simplify the
supply sequencing requirements."